# Node.js Application missing from Run Configuration

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

```
System Details
Machine: Mac Catalina
Eclipse: IDE for Javascript and Web Developers installed in system
Node version: v12.13.1
Protractor version: 7.0.0
```

I have created the Protractor project in eclipse and created config.js and spec.js file
[project structure in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW1F9.png)
 but when I tried to setup TestRunner I don't see Node.js Application under Run Configuration, not sure why it's missing
[node.js Application is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlHYZ.png)

Please let me know how to get Node.js Application under Run configuration so that I can create Test runner to un protracter test cases, similar to like this which is my expected screen under Run Configuration screen
[Expected Node.js Applicaiton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yAhz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use Nodeclipse https://nodeclipse.github.io/

File -> New -> Project -> Node.js Project

Choose "Hello Wold" project

Test is first

Then add your modules

see the demo screenshot https://nodeclipse.github.io/demos/navigation#/step-4

Comment: thanks but my problem was more in eclipse, I have installed SDK plugin in eclipse and able to create a test from Node.js Application